# Onlyfans like button, how to identify the element ID, Name etc

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate likes or button clicking using Python and `Selenium`, but I am struggling to find the correct element name to insert in my code:

```
Element= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "icon-like"))
)

Element.click()
```

But never works, say can't find the element, does somebody know the exactly one?[image]

I have tried to use `by.ID`, `by.Name`, `by.Xpath`, `by.CSS_SELECTOR`, any of these on attach.

Comment: right-click on the button and choose, "Inspect".  Copy/paste the element's markup into your post.  (The screenshot is not helpful...)

Comment: Thank you friend. But still not know which one to use, maybe you guys who access Onlyfans can tell how to reach the like (heart) element.